# Failure of recursive R package install

Tags: r, r-package

I'm debugging the reason why installing one's own package fails to install the `Import`-ed packages.

- Choose a suitable root directory. Launch an R session in that directory.
- After `library(devtools)`, run `devtools::create("mypackage")`.

Save the following lines in the file `mypackage/R/f.R`.

```
@#' export
f <- function() {
    fruits <- data.frame("fruit"=c("orange", "kiwi"),
                         "color"=c("orange", "green"),
                         "shape"=c("spheroid", "ellipsoid"))
    library(dplyr)
    colors <- select(fruits, fruit, color)
    colors
}
```

- Add `Imports: dplyr` at the end of `mypackage/DESCRIPTION`.
- Run setwd("mypackage") followed by `devtools::build()`.
- Run `remove.packages("dplyr")` (to subsequently install it recursively).
- Run `setwd("..")` followed by `install.packages("./mypackage_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`.

Installing `mypackage` should auto-install the package listed in the Imports line, but we get instead

```
ERROR: dependency 'dplyr' is not available for package 'mypackage'
```

Why?

N.B.: I am using `roxygen2` and a proper `NAMESPACE` file, but since this is my own package and I have [no intention](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) to submit it to CRAN, I consider these details irrelevant. (Are they?)

**Update**

If writing

```
Imports: dplyr
```

anywhere in `mypackage/DESCRIPTION` is necessary and sufficient to trigger a recursive install of `dplyr` whenever `mypackage` is installed, what is the significance or use case of adding the function

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    install.packages("dplyr")
}
```

in some `.R` file in the `mypackage/R` directory?

Is one method preferable, newer, or subsumes the other?

**Update 2**

Is it necessary to write

```
Imports: dplyr (>= 0.7)
```

?

If one doesn't specify the required version of each package, how can package installation be guaranteed to succeed? In other words, what is R's equivalent solution to Python's virtual environments?

Comment: Have you tried to quit all your R sessions and restart before installing?

Comment: @F.Privé I have. And also wiped out .Rdata for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `devtools::install("mypackage")`, this works for me.

Comment: The point is to release a package to a group of internal users. They should not need to use `devtools`, and any needed packages should install for them seamlessly.

Comment: Not sure what you ask is possible. Just give them a script which installs all the dependencies and installs the package from source.